# Very simple SD function

Tags: javascript, function

```
var orangeCost = function (pricePerOrange, amountOfOranges) {

    var totalCost = pricePerOrange * amountOfOranges;
    console.log(totalCost + " Dollar total cost");
};

orangeCost(5, 5);
```

```
25 Dollar total cost

NaN Dollar total cost
```

Why does it also log the "NaN" part instead of only the 25 Dollar stuff ?

thank you

Comment: Because you're calling the function a second time, in code you do not show us, and you fail to pass two numbers that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a [multiplication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Multiplication_%28%2a%29) could result in `NaN` is if the variables were `undefined`, meaning you're calling the function without passing `pricePerOrange` or `amountOfOranges`, **or** if one of the variables is a string.

Make sure you're passing variables to `orangeCost`, and that those variables are in fact `Numbers`.

Comment: `'string' * 3 = NaN` too

Comment: @Pudge601: Yea, I was editing that in when you commented :P

Comment: Yeah, had to open up a console to double check that one ;) I thought `null * 1` would be `NaN` too, but turns out it evaluates the `null` as `0`

Comment: I just went for the docs. It seems `Infinity * 0` is another case of `NaN`, while `Infinity * any other number` is still `Infinity`.